# What Should Be The Precautions While taking Care of pneumonia patient?

Tags: infectious-diseases, disease, pneumonia

What precautions should I follow while taking care of a pneumonia patient?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Are you asking about precautions to prevent getting infected or precautions for the patient (so as not to cause harm)? In general, it is a good practice to include some of your own research in questions on SE as well as provide as many details as possible. For more information on how the site works, please take our [tour] or visit the [help]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pneumonia-causing germs can become airborne and hence spread easily from person to person. While taking care of a patient recovering from pneumonia it is preferred to use a face mask so that there is minimum exposure to airborne droplets from the patient formed as a result of coughing or sneezing. Moreover, use of hand sanitizer is advised before and after visiting the patient as common surfaces e.g. table tops, door knobs and bed covers can be rich of body fluids from the patient. Generally, keeping a distance from people who are coughing or sneezing and washing your hands after every possible interaction can help protect against pneumonia in general.

Comment: A healthy person with normal immunity will unlikely catch pneumonia from another person with pneumonia. Microbes that cause pneumonia are contagious, but pneumonia much less likely. For example, if you are in contact with someone who got pneumonia as a complication of flu, you can get flu, but less likely pneumonia.